# Задача перечисление всех элементов в массиве, я хочу отобразить их с пробелом

Tags: php

```
$numbers = ['0', '7', '14', '21', '28', '35', '42', '49', '56', '63', '70', '77', '84', '91', '98',];


for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i ++) {
    echo $numbers[$i];
 }

//в результате числа перечисляться подряд, а я хочу с отступами, подскажите соответствующее действие
```

Comment: Хотите отступы - добавьте их.. `echo $numbers[$i] . " ";`

Comment: Помогло, благодарю)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$numbers = ['0', '7', '14', '21', '28', '35', '42', '49', '56', '63', '70', '77', '84', '91', '98',];

// вариант 1
echo join(' ',$numbers);
// вариант 2
echo implode(' ',$numbers);
// самый неверный вариант в данном случае
// к сожалению, ваш с циклом.
```

**P.S** старайтесь использовать циклы/foreach пореже. Это плохая практика использовать их везде, где можно и нельзя. Есть куча других классных ф-й в PHP которые больше подходят в текущей ситуации(это уже в общем, а не конкретно об этой)